# Load Another Form With Splashscreen VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, splash-screen

So I'm developing a game and it's a little heavy on some systems, so here's what I would like to do when the game opens (pseudo code):

```
Show Splashscreen
Load GameForm
When GameForm Is Completely Loaded
Splashscreen Close
Show GameForm
```

How is this done in actual VB code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open Visual Studio > new VB.Net Winform Project

Right click Solution > Add New Item > SplashScreen

Double click Form1 and in the Form1_Load event:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

Me.Visible = False

Dim s = New SplashScreen1()
s.Show()
'Do processing here or thread.sleep to illustrate the concept
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
s.Close()

Me.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

VB.NET 2010 (others?) has a built-in Splash Screen assignment mechanism.

Add a splash screen to your Winform project.
Project Menu -> Add New Item -> select "Splash Screen"

In the splash screen code window it gives you a hint how to do it.

```
'TODO: This form can easily be set as the splash screen for the application by going to the "Application" tab
'  of the Project Designer ("Properties" under the "Project" menu).
```

Basically, in the Project Properties, under the Application Tab, at the bottom, there is an option to select a Splash Screen.

The code that is added by this change to your project in the Application.Designer.vb file is:

```
    <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>  _
    Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateSplashScreen()
        Me.SplashScreen = Global.WindowsApplication1.SplashScreen1
    End Sub
```

By default, this method of assigning a splash screen shows it for 2000 milliseconds.

You can read the documentation for other usage [@MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.minimumsplashscreendisplaytime.aspx#Y0)